# Ubuntu 16.04 hangs on shutdown #8 (AMD GPU?)

Tags: 16.04, shutdown, amd-graphics, gpu

for last month or so my shutdown hangs with same output everytime. I have tryed every solution related to this question with no improvement (GRUB, systemctl, every possible update and upgrade, ...). Since there is an advice to take a picture of shutdown log via phone, becouse finding it in system is impossible ... I did that [picture of shutdown log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wu8Kz.jpg). I will provide any information that you would needed to help me with this situation.

Thank you for any ideas

I must be really dumb to not mention this earlyer. But this started to happen just a few days after I have instaled new GPU (AMD rx570 armor) I had to install drivers and update kernel. Is there any info that I can provide so anyone can help me investigate this couse?

Comment: Sometimes when you think it hangs, something is just really slow. Did you try waiting for a long time, like several hours? Does any additional message show up if you wait a long time? (I had a similar problem once and then it turned out that some process was waiting for some network communication that was unusually slow, but did finish after a while.)

Comment: Yes I have leaved that shutdown proces for an hour or even more. But nothing really happend.